# how to write xml data to an xml file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to write this xml string to a xml file using powershell.

I used the  below command:

```
echo '<service>
        <id>value</id>
        <name>value/name>
        <description></description>
        <env name="APP_HOME_DIR" value="%BASE%"/>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>-Xmx256m -jar "%BASE%\testservice.jar"</arguments>
        <logmode>rotate</logmode>
    </service>' > $targetlocation
```

but its not writing to the file in the correct xml format.

Comment: Your XML string is malformed: `/name>` -> `</name>`.

Comment: So, the question is how to write text to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, any language can have the problem of characters escape, in powershell, simply use following text block.

```
$xml = @'
whatever content here
<service>
    <id>value</id>
    <name>value/name>
    <description></description>
    <env name="APP_HOME_DIR" value="%BASE%"/>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>-Xmx256m -jar "%BASE%\testservice.jar"</arguments>
    <logmode>rotate</logmode>
</service>
'@
$xml | out-file 1.xml -encoding utf8
```

if you have variables need to apply, just use the format operator

```
$xml = @'
this is string 1 {0}, string 2 here {1}
'@ -f "string0", "string2"
$xml | out-file 1.xml -encoding utf8
```

Comment: Here's a quick [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) that explains the `@' your-text '@` format of the 'here string' that's been used in this answer.